# Spring Boot 2: Unable to start tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am new to spring boot.. Getting started by referring to the link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

After running the project its not starting the tomcat server.. Getting the error as **[ERROR] error reading /home/rahul/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.31/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)**

Not able to address this issue.. Any help would be appreciated.. 
Thanks a lot in advance..

My code is like below,

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wocs</groupId>
  <artifactId>REST</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Example.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have a corrupted file. Try clean your maven cache with `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository` and run again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a corrupted jar that is under your default `MAVEN` folder. You can delete the specific jar file that is causing this issue and trying the follow should help!

- Take a Maven update by right clicking on your Project -> then select Maven and then click on 'Update Project'. You've got to wait until these dependencies are downloaded.
- Run target `Clean Maven` (Project -> Run as -> Clean Maven)
- Then finally `Install Maven` (Project -> Run as -> Install Maven)

These steps should resolve your `invalid LOC header` error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on Windows 10:

1. Deleted this jar file from the shell command line
2. `mvn spring-boot:run`

After that, the jar was downloaded with no error and all is running fine.
and all is running fine